Touch-up Paint on Kitchen Cabinet Blemish Too Shiny
It's only been two weeks since our kitchen remodel was completed and I've already marked up one of the cabinets. The manufacturer provided us with touch-up paint but the sheen is off and it still looks terrible. The cabinets were painted with a sprayer and the touch-up paint came with a little brush, so I realize that is the problem. But what do I do about it? Is there any way I can dull the sheen?


You could try dulling the sheen a little bit with a gentle Magic Eraser application.  But I'd test first in an inconspicuous area, like maybe the inside of a door (assuming that was also painted).

Usually when I have to touch up the cabinets I install, I will test the touch up in a hiiden place to see how well it really does "touch up".
If it is only a small ding or scratch, the best approach is to place the paint only in the scratch. Also I need to add, when testing in the blind spot, I test for a thinner that will remove the paint if needed. Lacquer thinner has been my go to in the past, but test it first in a hidden area to make sure it does not remove the finish you wish to keep either.
With those few things known, I place the paint as carefully as I can only in the dig. Very hard to do. Many times I will litterally use my finger to touch it in, wiping the edges so the paint is not built up over and beyond the ding itself.
If it is a scratch, the thiner can come into play here. Once the paint is in the scratch, wipe the excess out of the scratch with a light dose of thinner, to only go over the scratch, and not into it, so as not to wash out the paint you need in there. This could work for small dings too.
Your issue you have there may only need to be wiped with thinner to reduce the amount that is beyond the ding, leaving the paint in it, not over the good surface.
If the thinner does not reduce the gloss too, again in a hidden spot, test 0000 steel wool, to deglaze the touch up, after you try it in a hidden place to make sure the 0000 steel wool does not change the sheen of the original surface.
Make sure these tests are done in the same light that the repair will be made in. Light and te reflecton of it, plays a huge part in how colors and sheen look on a finished product.
